# Using slaveOk for all queries

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I'm unsure of the proper way to use slaveOK with Connections::add(). It was suggested [here](http://lithify.me/bot/logs/li3/2012-05-01#23) to use `Mongo::setSlaveOkay()`, but I'd like it for all queries.

I'm unsure of how to properly test it, but I'd like to think this would work:

```
Connections::add('mongo', 
    array(
        'type' => 'MongoDb',
        'database' => 'my_app',
        'slaveOk' => true
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing - you could always fire up [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see where the requests are going, or check the log of the secondaries in the set to see if they are getting any reads.